# Drawing multiple rectangles in a view without using drawRect:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, drawrect

I have this code which makes multiple rectangles in a `UIView`:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.5);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

//newView.xPoints is always equal in count to the other two arrays below.    
for (int i = 0; i < [newView.xPoints count]; i++) 
{
    CGFloat tx = [[newView.xPoints objectAtIndex:i]floatValue];
    CGFloat ty = [[newView.yPoints objectAtIndex:i]floatValue];
    CGFloat charWidth = [[newView.charArray objectAtIndex:i]floatValue];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(tx, (theContentView.bounds.size.height - ty), charWidth, -10.5);
    CGContextAddRect(ctx, rect);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```

I tried it in `drawRect:` and it worked perfectly fine. However, I plan to use `drawRect:` for other purposes. So can anyone give me tips or hints on how to do it without using `drawRect:`?

Comment: You can do multiple things in drawRect, you know. You can wrap that code in a function and call it from draw rect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Inside of `drawRect:` is the only time that the current context is going to the screen. You will have to make your "other purposes" co-exist with this rectangle drawing code.

You can, however, factor this code out to another method, as long as it is only called from inside `drawRect:`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  The only time `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` is valid for your view is inside `drawRect:`.  You can draw to a layer outside of drawRect, but still you will have to draw that layer to your view in `drawRect:` if you want to actually see it.